# bash for loop through all sub directories

Tags: bash

I have one directory with 48 sub-directories such like:

```
output$ ll
total 0
drwxr-sr-x+ 1 xxx 576 Apr 27 16:39 ./
drwxrws---+ 1 xxx 254 May  4 15:12 ../
drwxrws---+ 1 xxx  28 Apr 19 16:31 404904/
drwxrws---+ 1 xxx  28 Apr 19 16:31 404905/
drwxrws---+ 1 xxx  28 Apr 19 16:31 405003/
drwxrws---+ 1 xxx  28 Apr 19 16:31 405050/
drwxrws---+ 1 xxx  28 Apr 19 16:31 405077/
...
```

I wanted to write a bash for loop to work on some common analysis in them such like:

```
for d in {404904,404905,405503,...};
do
    echo $d
done
```

My question is how to loop these sub-directories instead of manually type in.

Answer (score 1):

```
for d in */; do
  echo "${d%/}"
done
```